# http image from facebook breaks https certificate

Tags: wordpress, facebook, ssl

We are having a problem with a facebook image that loads through http instead of https and it gives a browser security warning.
The image is:
http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/zL/r/FGFbc80dUKj.png

This is a wordpress site, and there is no reference in the code to the image, nor to fbcdn.net.
The image doesn't either appear in the source code of the page once it's loaded.
Any ideas of how can we find what's loading that image?

Thanks,
Isaac

Comment: It could honestly be called from quite a few sources – a WordPress plugin, embedded Facebook comments, etc. Are you able to share the site URL?

Answer (score 0):

It's a plugin called intense debate, it loads a script from facebook that loads another script from facebook called all.js that loads the image.